# Restricting the thread access to a given block code

Tags: java, multithreading

I am recently using `Java Threads` and I am trying to implement a method able to restricts a block of code to be execute only by one thread, lets called "single".

One naive solution that I already implemented is as follows:

```
if(readFlag())
{
  synchronized(this)
  {
  flag = false;  
  // do some work
  }
}
```

Where :

```
public Boolean synchronized readFlag() {return flag;}
```

This naive solution works fine for only one "single" block, but the problem occurs when I try to use multiple "single" code blocks. Since I can not use the same flag, because different threads may whan to enter different "single" code blocks at the same time.

Another solution could be the use of an array of flags variables one for each "single" but this solution would have problems (or require the use of barriers) when executing "single" code blocks inside loops, beside not being very flexible.

My question is:

How could I improve this solution to allow the execution of various "single" code blocks and to allow the execution of the same single code block multiple times (e.g. a single code block inside a loop).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the object you synchronize on. There is no need to synchronize on `this`, unless you need to. If you have two blocks that need to be synchronized but that can both be executed at the same time (each by one thread only), you can do something like

```
private final Object lock1 = new Object();
private final Object lock2 = new Object();
...
synchronized(lock1) { // do stuff. the code in lock2 can be executed while another thread is executing this }
synchronized(lock2) { // do stuff. the code in lock1 can be executed while another thread is executing this }
```

Also take a look at the [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) for more sophisticated locking (to allow multiple readers but only one writer).

Answer (score 3):

I've come across a similar problem in past days.
In my case I had to perform a cleanup task in a ConcurrentMap, and only one thread should do the task every 10 minutes. I had no need to synchronize, as the ConcurrentMap iterator guarantees not to throw ConcurrentModificationException.
In order to be sure that only one thread would perform the cleanup task I used an AtomicBoolean:

```
AtomicBoolean flag = new AtomicBoolean(false);
...

boolean proceed = flag.compareAndSet(false , true);
if(proceed){
   doStuff();
   flag.set(false);
}
```

So this avoids synchronizing on the boolean flag. As per the different pieces of code to synchronize on, I agree with Jeff..you can synchronize on different objects.